# Power Automate converting a Individual/Claims to a string value

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that has a people picker field that is being transferred from a SharePoint list into alternate SharePoint lists depending on the various conditions.

I have no problem creating a new item in a wide variety of different lists using the Individual/Claims from the get items value in all other steps. This includes transferring the same value into the same list at a different point in the flow.

At one final step in the flow, Power Automate indicates that Individual/Claims is a string value and not an integer value.

This is the error it is giving:

"The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item_12' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/ResponderID' is required to be of type 'Number/double'. The runtime value '"i:0#.f|membership|tammy.lang@inspection.gc.ca"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'Number/double'."

This is how the field is set up.
outputs('Get_Updated_Details')?[?body/IndividualRequested/Claims']

As you can see, I have requested the CLAIMS field from the people picker.  That should be a numeric and not a string value.  The exact same output value has no problems in any other points in the workflow.  It is only happening on this one side of a condition.  Why is it giving me the EMail value instead of the Claims value?  How can I fix this?

I have copied the steps that work 100% at different points in the flow over to the impacted side of the condition, and Power Automate is still changing the Claims value into an Email String value.

I have created a new get items step, and Power Automate is still converting the claims to the email value.

Why does it work everywhere else in the flow and not at this specific point?

Desperately need to fix this.

Tammy

Comment: "i:0#.f|membership|tammy.lang@inspection.gc.ca" is definitely a valid SharePoint claims value. The error seems to be related to an ID field (ResponderID), which requires a number. As we do not know your environment at all, it will be very difficult to provide quality answers without more information. Adding some screenshots of your flow and the SharePoint list would greatly help.